# How to set json values to a model class directly in swift

Tags: ios, swift

**This is my json value**

```
"end_location" = {
        "location_name" = "";
        pLatitude = "<null>";
        pLongitude = "<null>";
    };
    "start_location" =         {
        "location_name" = "<null>";
        pLatitude = "<null>";
        pLongitude = "<null>";
    };
```

**i would like to set the data of this json to the class below**

```
    class busLocationAndDetails {
    class bus_location {

       var pLatitude:String!
       var pLongitude:String!

    }
    class busDeatils {

       var busStatus:String!
       var busName:String!
    }
  }
```

i will be accessing the data directly from the class
 **busLocationAndDetails.bus_location.pLatitude**
this must return the data from the json

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your going to use these classes for storing data it is better to use struct than classes.

```
struct BusLocationAndDetails {

    var busLocation : BusLocation
    var busDetails : BusDetails

    init(dictionary : [ String: AnyObject]){
        let latitude = dictionary["pLatitude"] as! String
        let longitude = dictionary["pLongitude"] as! String

        busLocation = BusLocation(lat: latitude, long: longitude)
        busDetails = BusDetails(status: "", name: "")

    }

    struct BusLocation {
        var pLatitude:String!
        var pLongitude:String!

        init( lat: String, long :String ){
            pLatitude = lat
            pLongitude = long
        }

    }
    struct BusDetails {
        var busStatus:String!
        var busName:String!

        init( status: String, name :String ){
            busStatus = status
            busName = name

        }

    }
}
```

Then you can save these values

```
var busLocationAndDetails = BusLocationAndDetails(dictionary: yourJson)
//yourJson value should be the values of the key end_location
```

Then you can get the values like

```
var latitude = busDetails.busLocation.pLatitude
```